# Get Location Details from Google Map to Application

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation

I need to open Google Map from my application, select a location, get its details like lat, long, address, etc and send this data back to my application.
I am not sure how to proceed. Need some insight.

I am able to open Map via intent, but not sure how to send back selected location back to my app.

**UPDATE**
I got what I wanted but not able to integrate it :(

[Place Picker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker)

following  [Place Picker Example](https://github.com/Truiton/PlacePicker)  but this is also closing after launching. I have created my Places API key and added to manifest file. I am also requesting for permission on API 23.

Thanks

Comment: use google map fragment in your app.

Comment: Solved it... Solution here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36077696/place-picker-closes-after-launching

Answer (score 0):

The Google Maps App does not handle the action that you want, but you can add the map to your application using the [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/).

Once you instanciate the map you can set a [GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener) on it:

```
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng clickPos) {
            // Here you have the user click
        }
    });
```

If you need to find the address (or most probable addresses) for that coordinates, then you can use a [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) to find it:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(clickPos.latitude, clickpos.longitude, 1);
```

The [Address](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Address.html) object will give you all the available information for that coordinate.

Comment: Place Picker could help me here. Not able to integrate it. It closes as I launch it !

Comment: Are you adding ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION to your manifest? Also, if you are building with API >= 23, you need to ask for permission in [runtime](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/permissions/requesting.html).

If this is not the problem, please check and send the adb log to see what is going on.

Comment: Yes, I am asking for permission

Comment: So please add the code to your question, so we can check that.

Comment: Solved it... Check solution here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36077696/place-picker-closes-after-launching