# Place Picker closes after launching

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, location, google-places-api

I am not able to launch Google Place Picker from my fragment.
Followed all the steps and forums for the root cause but not able to resolve my issue.

Links [Google Place Picker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker)
Already checked following without any success
[Android Place Picker closes immediately after launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067210/android-place-picker-closes-immediately-after-launch)
[Place Picker Automatically close after launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30434238/place-picker-automatically-close-after-launch)

I have created Google Places API for Android key and added to manifest

I have even tried a release build.

Only error message I receive is

```
03-18 12:02:32.524 1679-1900/? E/GCoreFlp: Location requests inside Google 
Play services must contain a tag to aid in debugging.  Use LocationRequestInternal.create to wrap your LocationRequest, and pass it to requestLocationUpdates.
03-18 12:02:32.527 29916-29916/? E/PlacePicker: Place Picker closing due to ERROR
```

Need Help

My Manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tyagiabhinav.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="KEY-REMOVED-ON-STACKOVERFLOW" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

My Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tyagiabhinav.test"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
}
```

My Fragment Code

```
package com.tyagiabhinav.test;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesRepairableException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlacePicker;

/**
 * Created by abhinavtyagi on 18/03/16.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment implements ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private View rootView;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private boolean isLocationServiceConnected = false;
    private static final String LOG_TAG = MainFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 7;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_fragment, container, false);
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                    .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                    .build();
        }

        Button btn = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Clicked");
                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(),
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Ask for Permission");
                    // Should we show an explanation?
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                        // Show an expanation to the user *asynchronously* -- don't block
                        // this thread waiting for the user's response! After the user
                        // sees the explanation, try again to request the permission.
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

                    } else {
                        // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Permission Available");
                    placePicker();
                }
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }


    private void placePicker() {
        if (isLocationServiceConnected) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Connected to location service");
            PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
            try {
                Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(getActivity());
                startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Not connected to location service");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Not connected to location service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult");
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Permission Granted");
                    // permission was granted, yay! Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    placePicker();

                } else {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Permission Denied");
                    // permission denied, boo! Disable the
                    // functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Location Permission is required for accessing Place Picker!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }

            // other 'case' lines to check for other
            // permissions this app might request
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null)
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Location Connection Failed");
        isLocationServiceConnected = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Location Service Connected");
        isLocationServiceConnected = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Location Service Suspended");
        isLocationServiceConnected = false;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was putting meta-data tag wrongly

corrected manifest file :P

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tyagiabhinav.test">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="KEY-REMOVED-ON-STACKOVERFLOW" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```